# CSS - Selecting a Descendant Element of a Descendant Element

Tags: html, css

If I had the HTML code,

```
<div class="group">
    <p>This paragraph has <code>inline code that should be selected</code>.</p>
    <code>This is a block of code that should not be selected.</code>
</div>

<div class="other">
    <p>This paragraph has <code>inline code that should NOT be selected</code.</p>
</div>
```

How could select only the `code` elements inside of `p` elements that are descendants of elements described by the "group" class? I'd like to keep it fairly general right now, so if I had a `code` element inside of an `em` element that was inside of a `p` element, I'd still like to select it.

I keep running into this question, so I would like to know if it's possible, rather than other ways to do it that don't actually address selecting a descendant element of another descendant element. However, I am new to HTML and CSS, so if I'm thinking about all of this all wrong, I'd like to know.

Comment: `.group p code {}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use two [descendant combinators](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) in your selector.

```
.group p code
```